# What is a hypersurface ring and why is it Gorenstein?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, gorenstein, cohen-macaulay

My question is about [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131652/canonical-modules) 
and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701484/if-r-is-a-local-ring-with-operatornameemb-dim-r-textdepthr-1-t):

In the first link Graham Leuschke says: "That is a *hypersurface* ring, **so Gorenstein**, so the canonical module is the ring itself."

> What is a hypersurface ring and why is it Gorenstein?

Thanks.

Comment: In this link (end of comment), a hypersurface ring is defined as a local ring "codepth R $\leq$ 1$. http://books.google.no/books?id=C5j4xCl8Q80C&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=eisenbud+hypersurface+ring&source=bl&ots=F7SVGldE4_&sig=MkvZsYujVPOKNO1YL_CRLw4yQX8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Ioo1U4uACsffsgbC_YGQCQ&ved=0CGAQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=eisenbud%20hypersurface%20ring&f=false

Comment: The title of the second linked question is the definition of a hypersurface ring, and the contents answers your "why is it Gorenstein" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching "hypersurface ring" at [googlebooks](http://books.google.com/books?id=W648YTNmClYC&pg=PA28&dq=%22hypersurface+ring%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FIk1U4KNBfHNsQS4tIDQBA&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22hypersurface%20ring%22&f=false) immediately got me this (pg 28):

> A Noetherian ring $R$ is called a hypersurface ring if $\operatorname{emb dim}(R)\leq \operatorname{Krull dim}(R)+1$

Graham Leuschke was just introducing this terminology for that particular combination of conditions. <s>The answer to "why is it Gorenstein" is precisely the question asked at the second question you linked.</s>

**Update:** Despite the similarity of the definition and the title of the other question, user26857 assured me that the above definition is not sufficient to be Gorenstein. After a bit of searching, I've concluded that Graham Leuschke is either using a different definition, or else had a momentary lapse during that statement. It would be wonderful if he could make some comment on the issue himself!

Comment: @user121097 Hmm, is it not the case that $emb dim(R)\leq depth(R)+1\leq Krulldim(R)+1$? I was betting this is why the comment was made. I could indeed have guessed too much,  so I take your comment very seriously.

Comment: Dear @rschwieb, you have to reconcile your comment under the question with your answer. For the record, let me mention that the above definition of a hypersurface ring doesn't imply that the ring is Gorenstein, that is, one can give examples of rings $R$ with $\operatorname{edim}(R)=\dim R+1$ which are not Gorenstein.

Comment: I'm sure I posted another comment after this one shortly after the edit I made to address it, but I don't know why there is nothing here now. Anyhow, the update to the solution above is supposed to address this concern.